What was the morphology of the crustacean common ancestor?
When talking about crustaceans my mental picture is of a lobster or a crab since those are the most iconic crustaceans. This made me wonder what was the morphology of the common ancestor of all crustaceans - did look like a crab or something else?
This is what I found from a cursory google search - https://www.cell.com/current-biology/pdf/S0960-9822(08)00658-1.pdf

While the fossil record does not give a clear picture of the morphology of the ancestor of all crustaceans (the ‘urcrustacean’), it has been argued that it probably would have had a fairly large number of identical or highly similar (homonomous) segments, each of which bore a pair of appendages. This inference of homonomous segmentation in the urcrustacean often leads to description of several extant groups, such as remipedes and branchiopods (brine shrimp, etc.) as ‘primitive’ — or more correctly, having retained ancestral bodyplan characteristics.

Is that correct in the most current understanding - that the urcrusteacan looked like a remipede? Are there any other details that can be inferred about its anatomy or morphology?

Relevant xkcd

There's no consensus as far as I'm aware - there is a deal of argument, including disagreement over the basis of the whole group of crustacea being a real (complete) group or a paraphyletic one. That being said, if xkcd is anything to go by, the common ancestor may be very far back and look nothing much at all  like a crab.

By which I mean, in the link there's an image, some crabs/shrimps etc. appear in the green group, and some things that look very like crabs are in the blue group on the left. Some are in the orange on the right - they all ultimately call back to a single ancestor, but diverged differently. It's more complicated than the diagram suggests and there's more than one common ancestor depending what you count as crustacea.

Would it have looked like a remipede then? Multiple undifferentiated segments, a bit like a millipede or a centipede I guess?
